# Sails Query Returns Nothing After count() Query

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sails.js

The following returns empty results when executed. It's fine without the Count query, but even still, the correct values are returned but the response is always empty. Am I having a race condition issue?

```
module.exports = {
getSites: function (req, res) {
    var sites = [];
    Site.find({ company: req.session.companyID }).populate('locations').exec(function afterFind(err, results) {

        for (index in results) {

            var siteObj = {};

            siteObj = results[index];


            sails.models['site_users__user_sites'].count({ user_sites: results[index].id }).exec(function found(err, counted) {
                if (err) {
                    sails.log.error(err);
                }
                sails.log.debug(counted); // Prints correct number
                siteObj['user_count'] = counted;
                sails.log.debug(siteObj['user_count']); // Shows value is present
                sites.push(siteObj);
            });
        }
    });

    sails.log.debug(sites); // Nothing
    return res.json(sites); // Nothing
},}
```

**Update:**

```
module.exports = {
getSites: function (req, res) {
    var sites = [];

    Site.find({ company: req.session.companyID }).populate('locations').exec(function afterFind(err, results) {
        var completedResults = 0;

        for (index in results) {
            sails.log.debug(results);
            var siteObj = {};

            siteObj = results[index];

            sails.models['site_users__user_sites'].count({ user_sites: results[index].id }).exec(function found(err, counted) {
                if (err) {
                    sails.log.error(err);
                }
                siteObj['user_count'] = counted;
                sites.push(siteObj);

                completedResults++;
                if(completedResults === results.length) {
                    sails.log.debug(sites);
                    res.json(sites);
                }
            });
        }
    });
},
}
```

After updating to the above, logging "results" produces all the correct records. However, when returning "sites", the two entries returned are duplicates.

**Update 2**

I have a feeling that the async query is not completing before the next item in the for loop is being accessed, thus assigning the values to the wrong object.

**Update 3**
Provided logs for help.

Here is the log for the "results"

```
[ { locations: [],
company: 1,
name: 'N',
id: 1,
createdAt: '2017-06-06T10:07:25.000Z',
updatedAt: '2017-06-06T10:07:26.000Z' },
{ locations: [],
company: 1,
name: 'W',
id: 2,
createdAt: '2017-06-06T11:08:08.000Z',
updatedAt: '2017-06-06T11:08:08.000Z' } ]
```

This is the log for "sites"

```
[ { locations: [],
company: 1,
name: 'W',
id: 2,
createdAt: '2017-06-06T11:08:08.000Z',
updatedAt: '2017-06-06T11:08:08.000Z',
user_count : 1 },
{ locations: [],
company: 1,
name: 'W',
id: 2,
createdAt: '2017-06-06T11:08:08.000Z',
updatedAt: '2017-06-06T11:08:08.000Z',
user_count : 1 } ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because

```
sails.log.debug(sites); // Nothing
return res.json(sites); // Nothing
```

Executes before

```
sails.models['site_users__user_sites'].count({ user_sites: results[index].id }).exec(function found(err, counted) {
    if (err) {
        sails.log.error(err);
    }
    sails.log.debug(counted); // Prints correct number
    siteObj['user_count'] = counted;
    sails.log.debug(siteObj['user_count']); // Shows value is present
    sites.push(siteObj);
});
```

To fix it, you need to call `sails.log.debug` and `res.json` once the async exec function has completed for all results. Like this:

```
module.exports = {
    getSites: function (req, res) {
        const sites = [];
        Site.find({ company: req.session.companyID }).populate('locations').exec(function afterFind(err, results) {

            let completedResults = 0;

            for (index in results) {

                const siteObj = results[index];


                sails.models['site_users__user_sites'].count({ user_sites: results[index].id }).exec(function found(err, counted) {
                    if (err) {
                        sails.log.error(err);
                    }
                    sails.log.debug(counted); // Prints correct number
                    siteObj['user_count'] = counted;
                    sails.log.debug(siteObj['user_count']); // Shows value is present
                    sites.push(siteObj);

                    completedResults++;
                    if(completedResults === results.length) {
                        sails.log.debug(sites);
                        res.json(sites);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: This works and returns correctly, except now I am receiving duplicated data. In this instance I am only retrieving 2 site records (which are correct after the first query) but then the response duplicates the last entry.

Comment: @BenBrookes Have you got an example?

Comment: @BenBrookes Have you got an anonymised example of the results object?

Comment: Added to my initial post.

Comment: Produced the same result unfortunately

Comment: Are you sure that's the log result from sites at the point that that if statement is true? It doesn't have the added user_count property. Also, are you also seeing this error if you request the API? i.e. if you get the value of res.json(...)?

Comment: My apologies, I got a bit too happy removing some of the fields. They do actually have the user_count property. And yes, the issue still remains.

Comment: It's because of the scoping of `var siteObj = results[index];`. What version of node.js are you using? `const siteObj = results[index];` should fix it. Or you can use a closure. Let me know and I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your help. That has fixed the issue. Marked as answer.

Answer (score 0):

find,count  and .exec are asynchronous in nature
You  are returning  the sites variable  , which is initally  an empty array , even before your afterFind function is computed , Not to mention the second exec after count .